# Android and Javamail; After updating JDK and ADT I'm getting Verify Errors?

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I've been using a javamail implementation previously in my applications, which i found here:
[javamail-android](http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/)

Until recently, everything worked fine. I simply added the .jar files as external jars under my build path. I recently updated to JRE7 and ADT 17, now i'm getting verify Errors! This seems to revolve around javax.mail.Multipart, but i am unsure how to fix this issue. Things I have tried:

1. adding the jars to lib/, linking source folder
2. adding jars to path from the lib/ folder
3. adding directly to build path
4. adding the Multipart.java source file

I can get as far as running the app, successfully verifying credentials, loading IMAP folders and messages, but i cannot get the Multipart content of the message now. This is where it seems to fail, and occasionally when first launching the library. below is the trace i have:

```
W/dalvikvm(16903): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/mail/Multipart;)
I/dalvikvm(16903): Could not find method javax.mail.Multipart.getCount, referenced from method com.control.process.MainActivity.getAttachment
W/dalvikvm(16903): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1033: Ljavax/mail/Multipart;.getCount ()I
D/dalvikvm(16903): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
D/dalvikvm(16903): Making a copy of Lcom/control/process/MainActivity;.getAttachment code (205 bytes)
W/dalvikvm(16903): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/mail/Multipart;)
I/dalvikvm(16903): Could not find method javax.mail.Multipart.getCount, referenced from method com.control.process.MainActivity.getMessageBody
W/dalvikvm(16903): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1033: Ljavax/mail/Multipart;.getCount ()I
D/dalvikvm(16903): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0001
D/dalvikvm(16903): Making a copy of Lcom/control/process/MainActivity;.getMessageBody code (168 bytes)
I/ActivityManager(64): Displayed activity com.control.process/.MainActivity: 1229 ms (total 2508 ms)
W/KeyCharacterMap(16903): No keyboard for id 0
W/KeyCharacterMap(16903): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
I/dalvikvm(16903): Could not find method javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance, referenced from method com.control.process.MainActivity$ServerCheckTask.doInBackground
W/dalvikvm(16903): VFY: unable to resolve static method 1038: Ljavax/mail/Session;.getDefaultInstance (Ljava/util/Properties;Ljavax/mail/Authenticator;)Ljavax/mail/Session;
D/dalvikvm(16903): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0060
D/dalvikvm(16903): Making a copy of Lcom/control/process/MainActivity$ServerCheckTask;.doInBackground code (2706 bytes)
W/dalvikvm(16903): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 271 (Ljavax/mail/NoSuchProviderException;)
W/dalvikvm(16903): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 271 (Ljavax/mail/NoSuchProviderException;)
W/dalvikvm(16903): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 271 (Ljavax/mail/NoSuchProviderException;)
W/dalvikvm(16903): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 271 (Ljavax/mail/NoSuchProviderException;)
W/dalvikvm(16903): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 271 (Ljavax/mail/NoSuchProviderException;)
W/dalvikvm(16903): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x1cc
W/dalvikvm(16903): VFY:  rejected Lcom/control/process/MainActivity$ServerCheckTask;.doInBackground ([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
W/dalvikvm(16903): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x01cc
W/dalvikvm(16903): VFY:  rejected Lcom/control/process/MainActivity$ServerCheckTask;.doInBackground ([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
W/dalvikvm(16903): Verifier rejected class Lcom/control/process/MainActivity$ServerCheckTask;
D/AndroidRuntime(16903): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(16903): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
E/AndroidRuntime(16903): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
E/AndroidRuntime(16903): java.lang.VerifyError: com.control.process.MainActivity$ServerCheckTask
E/AndroidRuntime(16903):    at com.control.process.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:197)
E/AndroidRuntime(16903):    at android.app.Activity.onOptionsItemSelected(Activity.java:2282)
E/AndroidRuntime(16903):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2170)
E/AndroidRuntime(16903):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:730)
E/AndroidRuntime(16903):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:139)
E/AndroidRuntime(16903):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
E/AndroidRuntime(16903):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuView.invokeItem(IconMenuView.java:525)
E/AndroidRuntime(16903):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView.performClick(IconMenuItemView.java:122)
E/AndroidRuntime(16903):    at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
E/AndroidRuntime(16903):    at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
E/AndroidRuntime(16903):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
E/AndroidRuntime(16903):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
E/AndroidRuntime(16903):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
E/AndroidRuntime(16903):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
E/AndroidRuntime(16903):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
E/AndroidRuntime(16903):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(16903):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(16903):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
E/AndroidRuntime(16903):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(16903):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(16903):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
E/AndroidRuntime(16903):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
E/AndroidRuntime(16903):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The only other idea i had was to revert to an earlier version of the JDK and the ADT build?
Need help on this one, any advice would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

For some reason while importing the necessary jar files, the mailcap settings get wiped out. I reloaded the settings before reading the Multipart message, and it works as expected.

MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
                        mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
                        mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
                        mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
                        mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
                        mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
                        CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);

Comment: try Project->Properties->Java Compiler-> [X] enable project settings [1.6] compiler compliance level and do a Project->clean on the whole workspace

Comment: I moved the java compiler back to 1.5 and cleaned the project. The verify errors stopped but it's still crashing on trying to read the message content as a Multipart message. It appears the contentType() is coming back as an IMAPInputStream, so i'm assuming the datahandler isn't correctly parsing the message. Now its showing a cast exception not being able to cast to Multipart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem because of these recent SDK changes:

[Dealing with Dependancies](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects)

What worked for me was removing the JARS from the build path, re-adding them and making sure they were marked as exported.

Peter

Comment: This seems like the more relevant solution. Thanks!